# SQL DATE_FORMAT in Alternative in Jooq

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I'm using 3.5 jooq version

I know that jooq don't support DATE_FORMAT function but what are the alternatives

This is the query that i want to create with JOOQ

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date_create`, '%d/%m/%Y') AS date_create FROM users
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date_create`, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you need a vendor-specific SQL feature that is not supported by jOOQ out of the box, the [plain SQL API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) will be your friend. Write a utility as such:

```java
public static Field<String> dateFormat(Field<Date> field, String format) {
    return DSL.field("date_format({0}, {1})", SQLDataType.VARCHAR, 
        field, DSL.inline(format));
}
```

You can then use it like any other jOOQ-provided function:

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(dateFormat(USERS.DATE_CREATE, "%d/%m/%Y").as("date_create"))
   .from(USERS)
   .groupBy(dateFormat(USERS.DATE_CREATE, "%d/%m/%Y"))
   .fetch();
```

Comment: Can i  use DSL.function instead in such cases rather than writing a Utility ?

Comment: @KaspaPhaniVardhan, yes you can, in case the generated SQL is of the format `function_name(arg1, arg2, ..., argN)`